# emberjs Computed Properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

At emberjs documentation http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_computed-properties-getters, says that there are two ways to define computed properties. First is through prototype extensions and the second is by wrapping the function in a call to `Ember.computed`.

Can anyone tell me what is the deference between them and if one way is better than the other, cause in example code there is no obvious deference (or i am missing something?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between both variants - except that the `Ember.computed` approach is more verbose. In fact, the `property` variant internally invokes `Ember.computed`, see definition in [function.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/8647bd5815ed1cbf6adcc70ad5e2771afdefc483/packages/ember-runtime/lib/ext/function.js#L64-67).

**packages/ember-runtime/lib/ext/function.js**:

```js
Function.prototype.property = function() {
    var ret = Ember.computed(this);
    return ret.property.apply(ret, arguments);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there is none in the end. As stated, you can use the `Ember.computed` if you don't like your `Function` prototype extended. Might be useful for metaprogramming as well.